# Adding custom control to Visual Studio toolbox?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio

How can I add my custom WinForm button to the Toolbox in Visual Studio?  I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming WinForms,

right-click on the Toolbox and select "Choose items". Click the Browse button and select the DLL with your button.

Answer (score 0):

Right mouse click it, click "Choose Items...".  When this has loaded, click Browse.  Locate your DLL/EXE and click Open.  It should then appear in the listbox.  Select it (if not selected already) and click OK.