# designer doesn't recognise usercotrols and classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I had a User Control start doing weird things with its events; it didn't call the load and layout events at all. I looked at the designer code and everything seemed fine. tried recreating the events in the properties windows, and still nothing.

as I didn't have this problem with other user controls i decided to delete it and make a new one with the same name. then it all went haywire - the designer of the main window suddenly stopped recognizing all the user controls and classes i've built for the project.

the design window just shows the same error repeating once for each user control or class:

> Could not find type '*Project Name*.*Class/User Control*'. Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built using settings for your current platform or Any CPU.

I tried restarting the PC, rebuilding all, cleaning solution, deleting the user control that caused the kerfuffle, recreating it, and changing solution to x64 and x86.

edit: it's a windows form application.

how can i get it to work again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find type 'xxx.xxx.xxx'. Please make sure that the assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009386/could-not-find-type-xxx-xxx-xxx-please-make-sure-that-the-assembly)

Comment: Is this WPF, WinForms, or WebForms?

Comment: it's a windows form application.  and I tried ideas from that thread, didn't work.

Comment: I think this will be hard to troubleshoot. Show us a print of your solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

It just randomly started working again. I literally haven't touched it since. but it's solved, I guess...